# Error no input file specified codeigniter on hostinger.in

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am getting this error. I cant't run my other pages. just only homepage open with domain name. I am working with free domain and hosting.

When I try to access other page it's show me erro **No input file specified.**

here is my htaccess code

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

AddType application/x-httpd-php .asp .py .pl

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.|/$) 
RewriteRule (.*) http://domainname.ga/$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I check lost of question before post question here. but can't get success.
any one can help me.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This Code in .htaccess works for me........

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```