# The page isn’t redirecting properly error in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect, http-redirect

I am getting a very unusual error, most of the time I can fix this `The page isn’t redirecting properly` very quickly as it's either something messed up with `htaccess` or in `php script` but I have looked for hours and can't find the single problem.

The page loads once with broken css and javascript files, and takes a long time to load but after that this error starts to appear and it'll only fade away when you clear the browsers cache then again the website loads for one time only before showing this error.

**Some details**

- .htaccess file is blank
- I tried loading just the welcome module only but the problem remains same.
- The server has been updated so I am wondering if this may have caused this problem.

I hope you guys can help me figure out why my website is on redirection loop, I can feel it's something related with cookies but I am not sure what.

**File Structure**

- application
- cgi-bin
- cronjobs
- system
- images
- system
- .htacess
- index.php
- test.php

**Edit:**

Website works flawlessly on localhost.

Comment: Could you please post your project structure?

Comment: @AmrAly Sorry but I didn't quite understand what you want me to post. Do you mean the file structure?

Comment: yes Please your file structure

Comment: @AmrAly I posted the file structure, hope it helps.

Comment: try to use a simple `.htaccess` like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406156/redirect-all-to-index-php-htaccess)

Comment: @user2801966 also in `config/config.php`, if `$confi['base_url']` is blank than add url to their also.

Comment: Make sure that all controller name stating with capital letter and also try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42924542/error-no-input-file-specified-codeigniter-on-hostinger-in/42925228?noredirect=1#comment72949126_42925228) .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

For future if someone stumbles upon this issue, I found out that the sessions were causing issues. I was auto loading the session library and when i removed it to test, it all started to work smoothly. So basically the main problem is with my php configuration and I have got my server guy to look into why the sessions are not working.