# Codeigniter 404 error, when hosted in ip

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

My codeigniter project is working on local server and also in another domain. But when I am upload it in **Digitalocean** with a ip pages show up but it gives a 404 error in the console.

Here is the link:

```
http://139.59.78.131/custom-shirt/fabric
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On  
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Set your base_url in config.php `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/'`;

Comment: Check your filenames and class names of controllers etc make sure only have the first letter uppercase.

Comment: I hosted it in Digitalocean

Comment: The put your domain there `$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.yourdomain.com/'`

Comment: It doesn't point to any domain yet.

Comment: Have you done this Check your filenames and class names of controllers etc make sure only have the first letter uppercase.

Comment: Yeah file and class names are fine

Comment: Try some of these htaccess if you want to https://github.com/wolfgang1983/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Comment: try this htaccess...[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42924542/error-no-input-file-specified-codeigniter-on-hostinger-in/42925228#42925228)

Comment: have u enabled mod_rewrite on your server?

Comment: How do I do it?