# .htaccess not working after updating ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, ubuntu

I had recently updated my ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04.
I am working with **codeigniter**.

Before update, all project was working fine but now no one project is working with .htaccess . I'm using htaccess to hide index.php from url.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

This is my htaccess file in the root folder of project.

Comment: Please define *not working*

Comment: defined @Capsule

Comment: is mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: from where. can you please explain ? @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Defined where? I can't see any update in the question

Comment: mod_rewrite is the Apache module that actually handles the rewrite. On your server (through ssh), try: `sudo a2enmod rewrite && sudo apache2ctl restart` and try your site again.

Comment: You may need to enable the rewrite module and restart the server. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14807463 (begin at step 3)

Comment: Thanks @Benson. It works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter htaccess and URL rewrite issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783666/codeigniter-htaccess-and-url-rewrite-issues)

Comment: try this answer its works on my ubantu VPS [CLICK HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42924542/error-no-input-file-specified-codeigniter-on-hostinger-in/42925228#42925228)

Comment: You're welcome @chigs; I originally posted the comment as an answer but I deleted the answer and reposted as a comment after @Narayan downvoted and flagged my answer was a more of comment, since it was more of a "try and see if this works" kind of answer. And you've marked it as an answer; and now I'm mystified as to how the world should work. Ha!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer, Givan by Benson in the comments.

**You may need to enable the rewrite module and restart the server. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14807463**

Answer (score -3):

You may miss `?` after index.php.

Change your

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

To

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```